# How to store math formula in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table contains the following data:

```
ID  | expression 
----|------------ 
1   | select 1+9  
2   | select 6+23+3 
----|------------
```

I need a query to get the result:

```
ID  | expressionValue
----|------------
1   | 10
2   | 32
----|------------
```

Comment: Do you want to provide an Id and calculate that Id's expression or to evaluate them all and output the result?

Comment: @Samir-Mohamed-Nasr-ElDinn, please note this solution can be dangerous. For ex. someone can add `3 | drop table MyTable`

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this:

```
declare @x nvarchar(100)
select  @x = expression from myTable where id = 1
EXECUTE sp_executesql @x
```

[image]

And if you want this to be done for all the rows of your table then try to create a cursor and execute it for your column like this:

```
DECLARE @myRes TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      expression NVARCHAR(100)
    )
DECLARE @temp TABLE ( ID INT )
DECLARE @ID INT ,
    @expression NVARCHAR(100)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  ID , expression  FROM  myTable
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @expression
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DELETE  FROM @temp
        INSERT  INTO @temp
                EXEC ( @expression )
        INSERT  INTO @myRes
        VALUES  ( @ID,  ( SELECT  * FROM    @temp ) )  
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID, @expression
    END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
SELECT  * FROM    @myRes
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you got only `+` and `-` in formulas - then you can use XML.query:

```
SELECT  ID,
        CAST(
            REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
            REPLACE(expression,'select ','<v><d>')
                                ,'+','</d><d>')
                                ,'-','</d><d>-') + '</d></v>' 
            as xml).query('for $s in /v return data(fn:sum($s/d))') as expressionValue
FROM YourTable
```

Output:

```
ID  expressionValue
1   10
2   32
```

Also you can avoid using dynamic SQL to execute `SELECT formula` statements and use more secure way with XML.query:

```
CREATE TABLE #Results ( --Table to store results
    ID int,
    expressionValue nvarchar(max)
)

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) --will hold the dynamic SQL query

SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql,'DECLARE @x xml = ''''; INSERT INTO #Results ') + 
            'SELECT '+CAST(ID as nvarchar(max))+' as ID, 
                        CAST(@x.query('''+REPLACE(expression,'select ','')+''') as nvarchar(max))  UNION '
FROM #YourTable  --query generation

SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql,LEN(@sql)-LEN(' UNION '))
```

If you make `PRINT @sql` you will get something like:

```
DECLARE @x xml = ''; 
INSERT INTO #Results 
SELECT  1 as ID, 
        CAST(@x.query('1+9') as nvarchar(max)) 
UNION 
SELECT  2 as ID, 
        CAST(@x.query('6+23+3') as nvarchar(max))
```

Then execute:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Then you can select from `#Results` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Results
```

Output:

```
ID  expressionValue
1   10
2   32
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
create table expr(id int,epres varchar(max))

insert into expr values(1,'select 2+2')
insert into expr values(2,'select 2-1')


declare @sql varchar(max),@id int
select top 1 @sql = epres,@id=id from expr where epres is not null order by id
while @@rowcount > 0
begin
    exec(@sql)
    select top 1 @sql = epres ,@id=id from expr where id > @id order by id;
end;
```